# How to color differently a part from line that lies between two selected vertices

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, line, color

I have a continuous line which represents the watercourse and I would like to color the parts that pass through pipes.

I would like to color differently the part that is between two selected vertices, knowing that the part is not segmented and it should not be segmented because the line constitutes a single attribute.

[image: Screenshot of data]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot colour individual segments within a single polyline. You don't state your license level, you should always say that as that dictates the solution. If you have an *Advanced* license then you could use the **Split Line At Vertices** tool to create a new layer of polylines composed of segments, delete the ones you do not need and then colour the remaining up at pipe sections?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't split the watercourse because the attribute table gives the exact length of the watercourse.

The vertices you saw in the previous image are from the vertex edit tool in an editing session. The watercourse contains no vertex.

I use ArcGis 10.3 with a professional license.

Comment: I think that you could still split the feature(s) and summarize the length based on a field that identifies an individual watercourse.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea that meat be helpful for you.
The first thing is to add anther name column into the Attribute Table [image]
Then use the "split features" to split the area you need to be painted[image]
Go back to the Attribute Table and right done a name in the area you need to be paint separately [image].
The change the symbolizing in the style layer into categorized and choose the name of your new column. Now click Classify and choose the color you need for each named section.[image]

Comment: I did what you suggested and I have seen that the length has not changed but the problem is that the number of attributes will increase and this will cause problem when I would publish the map for the general public and when people select a spesific watercourse, it will be just a part of a spesific watercourse and not the totaly.

Comment: The length is not supposed to change. It is still the same line but with marked area. Can you add some print screen so we can see what going on? I don't understand why it is a problem to have more row, the public is not exposed to the Attribute Table.

Answer (score 0):

First, I have one selected attribute.
[image]

After, I did what you told me before with the split tool:

[image]

When I select the attribute it's just only a part not the totality of the watercourse.

[image]